# Ubuntu 18.04 random freezes/crashes while using different applicaitons

Tags: 18.04, crash

I just installed Ubuntu on my old laptop, which has 4GB RAM and a 512GB SSD. Ubuntu is my only operating system, no dual booting.

I am experiencing frustrating and unexpected crashes in the middle of my work. When they happen, I can only reboot. I am not sure what is going on.
I am total beginner, not a coder, programmer or computer scientist.

Output of `ls -al /var/crash`:

```
total 88
drwxrwsrwt  2 root    whoopsie  4096 Oct 19 11:41 .

drwxr-xr-x 14 root    root      4096 Apr 26  2018 ..

-rw-r-----  1 grillea whoopsie 80634 Oct 19 11:41 _usr_bin_update-manager.1000.crash
```

Output of `free -h`:

```
         total           used       free      shared     buff/cache    available
Mem:       2.9G          1.1G        1.2G         24M        652M        1.8G
Swap:      2.0G             0B           2.0G
```

Output of `grep -i swap /etc/fstab`:

```
/swapfile    none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Thank you all for the replies.

Comment: I had similar effects on ubuntu 14 due to not having enough  swapspace while using a demanding application. Can you switch to an ascii console with Ctrl-Alt-F3 (you should be able to come back with ctrl-Alt-F2).  From there, you can run command line commands, like "top", to check if any process is abusing your CPU-resources.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al /var/crash` and `free -h` and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: When you update the information in your question, with requested information, remember to notify the requester with a comment that starts with @heynnema (for me).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Swap**

Let's increase your /swapfile from 2G to 4G...

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `dd` command can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

In the `terminal`...

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 4G RAM and 4G swap
```

Confirm this /swapfile line at the end of /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines...

To edit, use `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`

```
/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

**Memtest**

**Note**: Depending on the apps that you're running, you may need to add more memory.

Let's test your memory...

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take a few hours to complete.

Comment: This is what I see at the end of that script (base) grillea@grillea-ThinkPad-T60:~$ free -h 
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           2.9G        1.1G         91M         22M        1.7G        1.7G
Swap:          4.0G          0B        4.0G

Comment: @ImparoUbuntu Your `free -h` output looks fine. Did you run `memtest` yet?

Comment: I am workng on learning DD command to perform the memtest. I plan to use this machine for learning how to code in python and learning linux. Nothing else. A few questions for you. 1) would installing a less demanding than firefox, more basic browser help the machine running more smoothly for my purposes? if so which one would you advice? 2) would swapping the DVD drive with a caddy for a second HDD be useful?  3) Should I make a general comment on top so everybody can see your script work around solved my bug?

Comment: @ImparoUbuntu The `dd` command has nothing to do with `memtest`. The increased swap should make things run smoother. Do run `memtest`. Consider adding more RAM, if you can. Adding a 2nd HDD might be over the power capacity of the old laptop. You don't need to add a general comment... you accepted my answer... and that's all that's needed.

Comment: I was having a tough time downloading the memtest image  file. On their instructions they called for creating a bootable USB drive using the DD command. I  just  could not figure it out. Finally discovered that when I right click on the memetest file.img  Ubuntu allows you to use Diskwriter to do that. Creating the USB as we speak. Wish me luck.

Comment: @ Heynnema. The Memtest86 is a no go.  here I am quoting their manual :           All MemTest86 images support booting only in UEFI mode. If your system is unable to boot MemTest86, it is
most likely that either
1. You have an older system that does not support UEFI
2. Your system supports UEFI but is configured in legacy mode (ie. BIOS)

Comment: If you have an older BIOS computer, then hold down the SHIFT key at boot time. That should get you to the GRUB menu. Memtest may be a selection in that menu.

Comment: @ Heynnema. Black screen does not happen as often as before. But I still experience at least a couple of instances per day where things are going great. Then I open a new application and the new window is black. So I finally decided to run the memtest tonight from grub. It's been going for almost 2 hrs now and no errors. What did you mean by 'all the 4/4 tests"? Thank you.

Comment: @ImparoUbuntu It shouldn't take that long to test 4G RAM. If it's hung/frozen, then it probably means that you've potentially got some bad RAM. Stop the test if you need to, and re-run it. The 4/4 tests is how the normal memtest works. The GRUB memtest may just print out test #1/2/3/4/5/6/7/etc... but it'll tell you when it's done.

Comment: @ Heynnema. It's probably me not understanding the output. Wish I could post a picture of the screen. Right now it says: pass 1. Test#10.  Errors 0. At the bottom of the screen it states: **Pass complete, no errors, press Esc to exit**... It must be done.  Again thanks for taking the time.

Comment: @ImparoUbuntu Let's check one more thing. Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the EXACT make/model # of your computer or motherboard.

Comment: @ Heynnema.    `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version                                                                          79ETE3WW (2.23 ) `                                                                                                                     Lenovo T60 IBM thinkpad. I swapped old HDD 80 GB for SSD 512GB. It has 4Gib RAM. Intel Core 2 T7200 2Ghz. 64 bit. Due to CPU limitations it can really only use 3GiB of RAM even if the slots can take 2 DDR2 2GiB RAM sticks.

Comment: @ImparoUbuntu It looks like Lenovo doesn't tell us the current BIOS version. You have to use their utility, which requires Windows to run. See https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds015026-bios-update-utility-thinkpad-t60-t60p-wide-screen-models

Comment: @ Heynnema. Ubuntu is the only OS on this machine. I guess we reached the end of this rabbit hole :-).

Comment: @ Heynnema. I am rebuilding another old pc. `$ free -h total used free shared buff/cache available Mem: 7.7G 1.4G 4.7G 344M 1.6G 5.7G Swap: 4.0G 0B 4.0G code` .  In the script above would I simply change to  `dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=8000`

Comment: @ImparoUbuntu There's nothing wrong with 8G RAM and 4G swap, however if you wish to create a larger /swapfile, you change the 4096 to some multiple of 1024. Check your /etc/fstab for a /swapfile line.

Comment: @ Heynnema. What about swappiness? I was reading this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq but I am quite confused. Should I set `vm.swappiness=100` since I have so little memory in the 4GB Lenovo with HD? And should I set `vm.swappiness=1` in the desktop with 8GB ram and SSD to reduce writes?

Comment: @ImparoUbuntu In the 4G RAM/4G swap, I'd recommend setting vm.swappiness=80, and/or get more RAM. I don't know anything about your desktop machine. How much swap does it have? What is vm.swappiness set to now?

Comment: @ Heynnema It's a Dell AIO Optiplex 9020. It has 8GB ram 512SDD. Ubuntu 18.04 is the only operating system.   `vm.swappiness=1` in order to reduce writes to SSD, but I thought I triple checked with you.

Comment: @ImparoUbuntu Older SSDs weren't happy with swap, but newer SSDs have "wear leveling" and don't degrade with swapping. vm.swappiness=1 is wrong with 8G RAM. How much swap does this machine have?

Comment: Free- h says Swap  = 4G

Comment: Set it back to 60.

Comment: In the config file I also changed  `vm.vfs_cache_pressure=50` based on the same SSD concerns. Is that ok? Thank you.

Comment: I'd set that back to 100, or just remove it from /etc/sysctl.conf.

Comment: @ Heynnema Having trouble with my AIO Optiplex 9020 all of of a sudden. `free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.7G        1.4G        4.2G        134M        2.2G        5.9G
Swap:          4.0G          0B        4.0G`

Comment: `$ ls -al /var/crash
total 94492
drwxrwsrwt  2 root     whoopsie     4096 Oct  9 20:58 .
drwxr-xr-x 15 root     root         4096 Dec 16  2020 ..
-rw-r-----  1 grillea  whoopsie 93889664 Oct  9 20:50 _opt_google_chrome_chrome.1000.crash
-rw-r--r--  1   whoopsie        0 Oct  9 20:50 _opt_google_chrome_chrome.1000.upload
-rw-------  1 whoopsie whoopsie        0 Oct  9 20:58 _opt_google_chrome_chrome.1000.uploaded
-rw-r-----  1  whoopsie  2852391 Oct  2 22:55 _usr_bin_file-roller.1000.crash
-rw-r--r--  1 whoopsie        0 Oct  2 22:55 _usr_bin_file-roller.1000.upload`

Comment: I am sorry to keep bothering about this but it seems you are the only one with the correct solution. all of a sudden DNS not resolving. Connection to sites constantly interrupted. Unable to play videos. It was working fine for about 2 years.

Comment: @ImparoUbuntu Please start a new question. Place data like `free -h`, etc. into the question, not into the comments please. Try to stick to one problem at a time. Provide as much detail as you can.

Comment: will do. Thanks for your prompt feedback.

Comment: I posted it with title "Sudden DSL connection degrading - on and off - inconsistent slow connection to websites" I really don't know how else to explain it. Except what was once an excellent connection is now spotty and inconsistent